# change image jquery keeping onclick

Tags: jquery

I have an image that I want to change via jquery:

```
<div id="imagepr">
  <img class="imageprofile" src="$picimgprofile" alt="img" onclick="show_popup('popup_upload')>
</div>
```

the problem is, I want just to change the IMAGE (.imageprofile) and allow, after it, the onclick function to be called again.

If I change like this:

```
$("#imagepr").html(data);
```

it will destroy the onclick;
and this:

```
$(".imageprofile").html(data);
```

is not working.

what is wrong? how can I change just the image keeping the onclick after it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update only the `src` attribute of image, in this way you will not lose `onclick` attribute :

```
$(".imageprofile").attr("src","new-image-source");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, you probably dont want to be using inline `onclick` event handlers. Instead attach a click event using jQuery

```
$('#imagepr').on('click','.imageprofile',function(){
   // do whatever you want here when clicking the image
});
```

Later if you completely replace the content of `<div id="imagepr">` as long as it has an image with the class `.imageprofile` it will still respond to the same click event

Comment: oh, it is true, I will change this onclick for jquery click event!